# Protected variable not accessible within child class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility, protected, access-modifiers

I have the following structure -

`App.java` -

```
package JohnParcellJavaBasics.AccessModifierDemo;
import JohnParcellJavaBasics.AccessModifierDemo.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

`AnimalApp.java` -

```
package JohnParcellJavaBasics.AccessModifierDemo.Animal;
import JohnParcellJavaBasics.AccessModifierDemo.Animal.*;

public class AnimalApp {
    protected String animalName;
    public void myMethod() {
        
    }
}
```

`Eagle.java` -

```
package JohnParcellJavaBasics.AccessModifierDemo.Animal.Bird;
import JohnParcellJavaBasics.AccessModifierDemo.Animal.*;

public class Eagle extends AnimalApp {
    public void myMethod() {
        AnimalApp.animalName = "abc";
    }
}
```

In the file - `Eagle.java`, in the line `AnimalApp.animalName = "abc";` below `animalName` there is a read line which reads -

`The field AnimalApp.animalName is not visible`

How can this be possible?

I am using VSCode on Ubuntu and OpenJDK 11.

Comment: It's just `animalName = "abc";`  Why are you qualifying it with a _class_ name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you confusing static and instance members.

**AnimalApp.animalName** - is a way to refer to a *static* variable (by using the class name, because static variable resides on the class, they do not belong to any instance of the class and hence cant be inherited).

**this.animalName** or **super.animalName** or simply **animalName** - are proper ways to access *instance* variables

Comment: @alex87 'just animalName, even if it's not the best way' - actually it's absolutely normal to use a property name alone when it doesn't clash with the name of the parameter